# jQuery: howto add a <br/> line break in different strings to separate sentences in 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, split, line-breaks

I have different sentences which all have double quotes in them, like:

```
<h3 class="myClass">Sentence one "ends like this"</h3>
<h3 class="myClass">Sentence two"ends like that"</h3>
<h3 class="myClass">Sentence three "another ending"</h3>
```

All on a page. Basically all values are differents, and I'm trying to have a line break just before the double quote so it would be like

```
<h3 class="myClass">Sentence one <br/>"ends like this"</h3>
<h3 class="myClass">Sentence two <br/>"ends like that"</h3>
<h3 class="myClass">Sentence three <br/>"another ending"</h3>
```

I'm kind of confused on which jQuery function should be used to be honest, between split, text ? Any help would be appreciated , I need to understand how to do this... Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the `<h3>` elements, then pass a function to [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/). That function will be called for each element, will be passed the current element's inner HTML markup, and must return the new markup.

From there, you can use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to insert a `<br />` element before the first double quote character:

```
$("h3.myClass").html(function(index, currentHtml) {
    return currentHtml.replace('"', '<br />"');
});
```

You can test this solution in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXUcw/).

Comment: okay got it, thanks for the short code solution and explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://jsbin.com/uwihow/3/) to see this code working:

```
$(".myClass").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var q = text.indexOf('"');
    $(this).html(text.substr(0, q) + "<br />" + text.substr(q));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that takes a jQuery object, gets its html, and changes it

```
function addBR($el) {
```

Get the element's html

```
var originalhtml = $el.html();
```

Split the html by the quotation mark, and join them with a new <br />

```
var newhtml = originalhtml.split('"').join('<br />"');
```

Apply the new html

```
$el.html(newhtml);
```

And that's it.
Call it with

```
addBR(jQuery element);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XFC5u/

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [Javascript split() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) but in essence you have the right idea. You want to split based on the double quote(\") and that will return you an array of all the splits where a double quote occurs.

So something like this would happen:

`var array = $(".myClass").text().split("\"");`
`//array = [Sentence one, ends like this, ];`

(Not 100% sure if code is right so someone please check ><)

and then from there you can kind of recreate the text with the included 
. At least that's the process of how I would go about it.

Also just remember that the split method does remove the \" from the array (because it uses it as a limiter to split them) so make sure to readd them when you are recreating the text.

As for if Jquery as a specific way of doing this, I'm not sure. If anyone would like to improve my answer, feel free.

Answer (score 1):

just with some basic javascript (inside a jQuery loop offcourse)

```
​$(".myClass").each(function() {   // for each item of myClass 
   var text = $(this).text();     // temp store the content
   var pos = text.indexOf('"');   // find the position of the "
   $(this).html(text.slice(0,pos) + '</br>' + text.slice(pos));    // slice before + <br> + slice after = new content
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JaPdT/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){ 
    if($(this).text().indexOf('"') >=0 ){  
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace('"', '<br/>"')  )   
    }
})
```