# How to prepend line break before special character

Tags: jquery, find, prepend

I need to add a line break immediately prior to every instance of a parenthesis using JavaScript (specifically jQuery).

I've been unable to locate any documentation that indicates I can search a string, by specifying it's class/ID, for a special character (in this case the parenthesis) and prepend HTML to it.

Can anyone assist me? Thank you!

Comment: Why javascript and not server code?

Comment: Because the code it's searching is being generated by JS as well after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: So... add the linebreaks during the process of generating it?

Comment: I am unable to modify that code in this case. But Shivam provided a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#unique").html( function(i, oldtext){
    return oldtext.replace("(","<br> (");
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gG7B8/2/)**

Comment: Thank you Shivam. I eventually found this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062179/jquery-howto-add-a-br-line-break-in-different-strings-to-separate-sentences